# CSS How can I make this height responsive?

Tags: html, css, height, css-position

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 7%;
  height: 79vh;
  background-color: green;
  background-size: 300px;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <h1>TEST</h1>
</section>
```

As you can see it somewhat responsive but when I close the window to below 1200px the top will have more white space then the bottom, how can I fix this?

Also I used `vh` but tbh it's a bit of a dirty to way to position. If I had no height it will only show the first `<h1>` any other way around that?

Comment: Height by default is responsive... What is the main idea of this? Vertical-align green box?

Comment: can you show us what you want to obtain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you have in mind.?

```css
.wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    height:60%;
    width:60%;
    background-color: green;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
</section>
```